# imagecreatefromjpeg parameter not working

Tags: php, image-processing, php-gd

I have used imagecreatefromjpeg("1.jpg")  it is showing

```
Warning: imagecopy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in E:\wamp\www
```

I am not understanding why it is not working and it tacks as a string, though it is a existing image name on the same file.

```
$new_image = "assets/small/i/m/".imagecreatetruecolor($size_width, $size_height);
            $file = "upl_13541718681354171868The-best-top-desktop-dolphin-wallpapers-hd-dolphins-wallpaper-3.jpg";
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size_width, $size_height);
imagejpeg($imageOutput, $outputPath, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imagecreatefromjpeg
```

Returns an image resource identifier on success, FALSE on errors.

so you are probably passing false to

```
 imagecopy
```

edit

sorry, parameter 1 is the destination. your're passing a string instead of a resource:

From docs:

```
// Create image instances
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);

// Copy
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);
```

Comment: $new_image = "assets/small/i/m/".imagecreatetruecolor($size_width, $size_height);
   $file = "upl_13541718681354171868The-best-top-desktop-dolphin-wallpapers-hd-dolphins-wallpaper-3.jpg";imagecopy($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size_width, $size_height);
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

Comment: your problem is $new_image = "assets/small/i/m/".imagecreatetruecolor($size_width, $size_height); thats a string. This is a resource: $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($size_width, $size_height);

Comment: I want to save the new file under assets/small/i/m/ then what shall I do ?

Comment: imagejpeg($new_image, "assets/small/i/m/" . $some_filename, 100);